# 1D image deblurring using line spread function and Wiener Filter

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fft

I have been reading up on using the wiener filter to deblur or "restore" a 3D image. The difference between my approach and that used in the MATLAB function "deconvwnr" is that I am not interested in deblurring the image in all 3D dimensions (x,y,z) only in the z-dimension. My theory is that if I know the line spread function (LSF) in the z-dimension (LSF_z) then I can use the wiener filter and the LSF_z to deblur the image in the z-dimension.

### My stab at the code is as follows:

```
close all
% Define LSF (i.e. gaussian with mean = 0.5 & FWHM = 0.2)
    space=linspace(0,1,50)';
    space=fftshift(space);
    FWHM=.2;
    sigma=FWHM/2.3548;
    c=0.5;
    h = gaussmf(space,[sigma c]); % LSF 
% Define degradation function frequency cutoff
    Hcut=1e-7; % 
    Flpcut=1e-7;
% Define Transfer Function
    H=fftshift(fft(h)');

    [nx ny nz]=size(I);
    Ideconv=zeros(size(I)); % allocate memory for "true" image

    eps=1e6; % regularization parameter (i.e. constant noise to signal ratio)

% Loop over all voxels in 2D space
for j=1:ny
  for i=1:nx
    % Flp: FFT of line profile in z-dimension 
        lp=squeeze(I(i,j,:));
        Flp=fftshift(fft(lp));

    % cut-off all frequences below Flpcut
    Flp=(Flp>Flpcut).*Flp; 

% Define power spectrum of degradation function and cut-off all
% frequences below Hcut
    magsquared=(H>Hcut).*abs(H).^2; 

% Inverse FFT of (Wiener Filter x Flp) 
    Ideconv_1D_z=ifft(ifftshift((H2>Hcut.*magsquared./(H.*(magsquared+eps))).*Flp)); 

% Place "deblurred" line profile into true image matricx
    Ideconv(i,j,:)=Ideconv_1D_z; 

  end
end
```

Data sample:

```
 a=squeeze(I(250,500,:));
 a=[70
    64
    64
    57
    57
    54
    58
    59
    55
    55
    51
    52
    51
    52
    55
    57
    58
    66
    64
    66
    69
    68
    65
    66
    66
    62
    56
    55
    54
    54
    55
    58
    63
    69
    65
    52
    52
    53
    55
    58
    58
    58
    59
    60
    60
    56
    56
    55
    55
    57
    60
    58
    61
    61];
```

Pseudo-code for plotting results:

NOTE: For the sake of simplicity,this is only plotting the results for a single line profile (i=400 and j=600)

```
subplot(2,2,1); 
     plot(real(Flp),'b')
     plot(imag(Flp),'r')
     title('FT of line profile')
     legend('real(Flp)','imag(Flp')
subplot(2,2,2); 
     plot(real(H),'b')
     plot(imag(H),'r')
     title('FT of LSF')
     legend('real(H)','imag(H)')
subplot(2,2,3)
     plot(magsquared,'b');
     title('Power Spectrum: magsquared')
subplot(2,2,4)
     plot(lp,'r')
     plot(I,'b');
     legend('original','deconvolved')
     title(sprintf('Line Profile results with FWHM=%1.2f',FWHM))
```

I believe my issue is with indexing and/or the frequency cut-off. When I plot the results they are not what I am looking for. Specifically, they are not nearly as dependent on the FWHM of the LSF as they should be.

Furthermore, I am surprised that the FT of a gaussian has an imaginary component since a gaussian is a real and even fxn which should produce a real and even FT.

[image: Output plots]

Comment: Could you add some sample data as well, please.

Comment: @kkuilla no problem. Thanks for your help. The image size is relatively large (approximately 800 x 1200 x 50) For this reason in only makes sense to show sample data for a line profiles.            a=squeeze(I(532,252,:));                                        a=[104,106,97,103,95,86,85,91,92,97,98,97,97,96,89,92,93,91,90, 90,89,89,91,91,95,97,104,105,106,103,97,101,99,101,98,99,97,95,92,96,102,98,101,97,93,94,90,89,89,84]      My apologies for the formatting

Comment: It's better if you add it to the question.

Comment: @kkuilla Done. Your help is greatly appreciated. I have been stuck on this problem for quite some time